# How do you create a First Person Object in LWJGL?

Tags: java, lwjgl

I am making a FPS, and I have gotten the Camera and World set up.
But I can't seem to draw a gun/object from a 3D Model on the bottom
right hand corner of my screen, like a normal FPS.

I have searched all over the internet and I can't find a tutorial that describes how to do this in Java, using LWJGL.
So is it possible to do this?

I appreciate all feedback! Thanks!

Comment: Did you try using a game engine e.g. jmonkeyengine has examples ready for that do what you want for a FPS.

Comment: Not yet, as I would prefer not to use an engine. But I will check it out!

Comment: I can't seem to find any guide or tutorial in Jmonkey. Could you please be a bit more specific?